# image detect text orientation (0, 90, 180, 270) degrees

Tags: java, image-processing, text-recognition

I'm searching for a plain java solution to detect the text orientation (0, 90, 180, 270) degrees on an image. I already tried it with the Hough-Transform algorithm, but without success.

Is there any other algorithm I can use?

Best

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect text orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783061/detect-text-orientation)

Comment: @Michael it's the same question (same url) not a duplicate ;)

Comment: @MoritzPetersen It's not a duplicate, because a tried the Hough-Transformation, but I failed.

Comment: @sbo Oops. I meant to add Moritz' link. The answers there include an alternative to Hough-Transformation.