# Getting Text Orientation Using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to get text orientation (i.e. angle) using OpenCV or any Image Pre-processing Library.

The Images contains no text skew however the Image itself is tilted

## For Example:

[image]

I have found a code that detects text skew, I would like to modify it solve my case

```
# load the image from disk
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])

# convert the image to grayscale and flip the foreground
# and background to ensure foreground is now "white" and
# the background is "black"
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.bitwise_not(gray)

# threshold the image, setting all foreground pixels to
# 255 and all background pixels to 0
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255,
    cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# grab the (x, y) coordinates of all pixel values that
# are greater than zero, then use these coordinates to
# compute a rotated bounding box that contains all
# coordinates
coords = np.column_stack(np.where(thresh > 0))
angle = cv2.minAreaRect(coords)[-1]

# the `cv2.minAreaRect` function returns values in the
# range [-90, 0); as the rectangle rotates clockwise the
# returned angle trends to 0 -- in this special case we
# need to add 90 degrees to the angle
if angle < -45:
    angle = -(90 + angle)

# otherwise, just take the inverse of the angle to make
# it positive
else:
    angle = -angle
```

Comment: What sorts of text do you want to analyse? Just plain English without pictures?

Comment: An Image contains English words

Comment: This question has already been answered. Have a look at this post:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783061/detect-text-orientation